# Couldn't able to use "@use" in sass

Tags: html, css, sass

I tried to use **@use** instead of **@import**,but it gives me compiling error when i try to use one.
compiling error is shown in the image below

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Poppins:wght@600&display=swap');

$fontsize:1.8rem;
$fontheading:'Poppins', sans-serif;
$fontbody:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
//colors
$pink:hsl(322, 100%, 66%);
$palecyan:hsl(193, 100%, 96%);
$darkcyan:hsl(192, 100%, 9%);
$grayishblue:hsl(208, 11%, 55%);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you have within _variables.scss?

Comment: Try to import your file as `@use "variables"` (given your variable file is in the same directory as `style.scss`)